# How to get multi-select in one query result using T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, join, select

I have two query statements, the results for the two statements appear on two lines.

I want to get all result in only one line.

This is the code:

[image: The Code]

```
select 
    [dbo].[HrPslEmployee].[EmployeeFirstName],
    [dbo].[HrTaWorkPeriod].[NameAR], 
    [StartTime] as ReqStartTime 
from 
    [dbo].[HrTaEmployeeWorkPeriod]  
join 
    [dbo].[HrTaWorkPeriod] on [dbo].[HrTaEmployeeWorkPeriod].[WorkPeriodId] = [dbo].[HrTaWorkPeriod].[HrTaWorkPeriodID] 
join 
    [dbo].[HrPslEmployee] on [dbo].[HrTaEmployeeWorkPeriod].[HrPslEmployeeID] = [dbo].[HrPslEmployee].[HrPslEmployeeID] 
where 
    [dbo].[HrPslEmployee].[HrPslEmployeeID] = 13 
    and [dbo].[HrTaEmployeeWorkPeriod].[WorkPeriodId] = 2

select 
    [dbo].[HrTaWorkPeriod].[NameAR], [StartTime] as ReqStartTime
from 
    [dbo].[HrTaEmployeeWorkPeriod]  
join 
    [dbo].[HrTaWorkPeriod] on [dbo].[HrTaEmployeeWorkPeriod].[WorkPeriodId] = [dbo].[HrTaWorkPeriod].[HrTaWorkPeriodID]
join 
    [dbo].[HrPslEmployee] on [dbo].[HrTaEmployeeWorkPeriod].[HrPslEmployeeID] = [dbo].[HrPslEmployee].[HrPslEmployeeID]
where 
    [dbo].[HrPslEmployee].[HrPslEmployeeID] = 13 
    and [dbo].[HrTaEmployeeWorkPeriod].[WorkPeriodId] = 3
```

Comment: Can you share your table structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can join the queries `ON [NameAR]`:

```
select a.[EmployeeFirstName], a.[NameAR], a.ReqStartTime, b.ReqStartTime AS ReqStartTime2
from (
  select [dbo].[HrPslEmployee].[EmployeeFirstName] , [dbo].[HrTaWorkPeriod].[NameAR] ,
    [StartTime] As ReqStartTime 
  from [dbo].[HrTaEmployeeWorkPeriod] 
  join [dbo].[HrTaWorkPeriod] on [dbo].[HrTaEmployeeWorkPeriod].[WorkPeriodId] = [dbo].[HrTaWorkPeriod].[HrTaWorkPeriodID] 
  join [dbo].[HrPslEmployee] on [dbo].[HrTaEmployeeWorkPeriod].[HrPslEmployeeID] = [dbo].[HrPslEmployee].[HrPslEmployeeID] 
  where [dbo].[HrPslEmployee].[HrPslEmployeeID] = 13 
  and [dbo].[HrTaEmployeeWorkPeriod].[WorkPeriodId]=2
) a inner join (
  select [dbo].[HrTaWorkPeriod].[NameAR] ,[StartTime] As ReqStartTime
  from [dbo].[HrTaEmployeeWorkPeriod] 
  join [dbo].[HrTaWorkPeriod]
  on [dbo].[HrTaEmployeeWorkPeriod].[WorkPeriodId] = [dbo].[HrTaWorkPeriod].[HrTaWorkPeriodID]
  join [dbo].[HrPslEmployee] 
  on [dbo].[HrTaEmployeeWorkPeriod].[HrPslEmployeeID] = [dbo].[HrPslEmployee].[HrPslEmployeeID]
  where [dbo].[HrPslEmployee].[HrPslEmployeeID] = 13 
  and [dbo].[HrTaEmployeeWorkPeriod].[WorkPeriodId]=3
) b on b.[NameAR] = a.[NameAR]
```